# Override Method in Builder

Tags: java, methods, overriding, builder

Example class:

```
public class Example {

    public boolean exampleMethod() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

So, now I wanted to add a Builder class (of course I have more things in my Example class). In there, I'd like to override the `exampleMethod()` method.

So I would like to do something like this:

```
ExampleBuilder builder = new ExampleBuilder();
//override method
```

Builder:

```
public class ExampleBuilder {

    //somehow override the exampleMethod with
    //given arguments (I could do it with
    //ExampleBuilder extends Example
    //but I don't think that is right)

}
```

Thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: Override it _where_? On what instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Override a declaration of method from interface, so instead you can use :

```
interface Example {
    public boolean exampleMethod();
}

class ExampleBuilder implements Example{

    @Override
    public boolean exampleMethod() {
      ///
    }
}
```